# How to pass an id dynamically in an query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the below query I need to pass a dynamic person_id, it has to run until the last person_id in the table.

```
select 
  rb.pk_room_bed_id,rb.fk_hostel_floor_room_id,
  hfr.fk_room_type_id,hfr.fk_room_share_type_id,hf.fk_hostel_id,
  pba.fk_person_id,rsp.price,rb.vacated_date,rb.allotted_date
from room_bed rb,
  hostel_floor_room hfr,
  hostel_floor hf,
  person_bed_allocation pba,
  room_share_price rsp,person ps
where 
  hfr.pk_hostel_floor_room_id = rb.fk_hostel_floor_room_id and
  hf.pk_hostel_floor_id = hfr.fk_hostel_floor_id and
  rsp.fk_hostel_id = hf.fk_hostel_id and
  rsp.fk_room_share_type_id= hfr.fk_room_share_type_id and
  hfr.fk_room_type_id = rsp.fk_room_type_id and
  pba.fk_room_bed_id = rb.pk_room_bed_id and
  pba.fk_person_id = 1;
```

Comment: Hi @mungara-pallavi! please edit your question add more description and structure of involved tables.

Comment: You should really starting using "modern" (> 25 years old) explicit `JOIN` operators rather than the ancient and fragile implicit joins in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inline subquery to determine the value.  I assume the last person_id is from the person table, so with that in mind:

```
select 
  rb.pk_room_bed_id,rb.fk_hostel_floor_room_id,
  hfr.fk_room_type_id,hfr.fk_room_share_type_id,hf.fk_hostel_id,
  pba.fk_person_id,rsp.price,rb.vacated_date,rb.allotted_date
from
  room_bed rb,
  hostel_floor_room hfr,
  hostel_floor hf,
  person_bed_allocation pba,
  room_share_price rsp,
  person ps
where 
  hfr.pk_hostel_floor_room_id = rb.fk_hostel_floor_room_id and
  hf.pk_hostel_floor_id = hfr.fk_hostel_floor_id and
  rsp.fk_hostel_id = hf.fk_hostel_id and
  rsp.fk_room_share_type_id= hfr.fk_room_share_type_id and
  hfr.fk_room_type_id = rsp.fk_room_type_id and
  pba.fk_room_bed_id = rb.pk_room_bed_id and
  pba.fk_person_id = (select max (person_id) from person)
```

Also, your syntax is non-ANSI.  Strictly speaking, there is nothing wrong with that, but from what I can tell you are missing a join.  You have listed the `person` table, but there is no join criteria to that table, which means you just invoked a cross join.  My guess is that's not what you meant.

One of the advantages of the ANSI syntax is it makes it easier to identify missing joins.  This query translated to ANSI would show where the join was missing:

```
select 
  rb.pk_room_bed_id,rb.fk_hostel_floor_room_id,
  hfr.fk_room_type_id,hfr.fk_room_share_type_id,hf.fk_hostel_id,
  pba.fk_person_id,rsp.price,rb.vacated_date,rb.allotted_date
from
  room_bed rb
  join hostel_floor_room hfr on
    hfr.pk_hostel_floor_room_id = rb.fk_hostel_floor_room_id
  join hostel_floor hf on
    hf.pk_hostel_floor_id = hfr.fk_hostel_floor_id
  join person_bed_allocation pba on
    pba.fk_room_bed_id = rb.pk_room_bed_id
  join room_share_price rsp on
    rsp.fk_hostel_id = hf.fk_hostel_id and
    rsp.fk_room_share_type_id= hfr.fk_room_share_type_id and
    hfr.fk_room_type_id = rsp.fk_room_type_id
  join person ps on
    -- WOA -- someting is missing!
where 
  pba.fk_person_id = (select max (person_id) from person)
```

Which, at the very least would cause a syntax error, whereas the query above would work but would have translated to:

```
cross join person ps
```